# How can I find a value of a state variable in React js when data is retrieved from Firebase database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I have happily managed to set my state variable named walletData with data from Firebase. Now I have a stupid problem that I can't get the value out, for example

```js
let someNumber = this.state.walletData.walletSaldo
```

Console.log displays {saldo: 1500}. Firebase tree looks like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48r3S.png)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
this.state.walletData.walletSaldo.saldo
```